# How do I assign specific partition keys to each pod for a Kafka consumer in a microservice running on a Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, partitioning

I have a microservice which runs on 3 pods in a Kubernetes cluster. This service has a Kafka consumer which listens to a Kafka topic. I want that a specific pod listens to message having a specific key value. How can I do that?

We could do something like this:

```
        // Create Kafka consumer
        KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);

        // Get the list of partitions for the topic
        List<PartitionInfo> partitions = consumer.partitionsFor(topic);

        // Find the partition(s) for the key value
        List<TopicPartition> assignedPartitions = new ArrayList<>();
        for (PartitionInfo partitionInfo : partitions) {
            String key = partitionInfo.leader().host();  // Use any key from the PartitionInfo
            if (key.equals(keyToAssign)) {
                TopicPartition topicPartition = new TopicPartition(topic, partitionInfo.partition());
                assignedPartitions.add(topicPartition);
            }
        }

        // Assign partitions to the consumer
        consumer.assign(assignedPartitions);
```

But I can't hardcode the `keyToAssign` in the code since that is the thing that has to be specific to the pod.

Answer (score 0):

> listens to message having a specific key value

This is not a proper use-case for Kafka consumers, but you'd use an environment variable on the container of the pod, not `PartitionInfo`

And use subscribe, not assign, then check it while looping over the records.

```
for (ConsumerRecord<String, ?> record: consumer.poll()) {
  if (record.key().equals(System.getEnv("FILTER_KEY")) {
    // process(record);
  } 
}
```

If you want to set a specific partition for a known key, you'd invoke `DefaultPartitioner` class, not `consumer.partitionsFor`

---

The other option is to deploy separate services.

1. Read all key-value pairs and build a KTable.
2. Use Interactive Queries to send RPC requests, looking for that key